# Is there any word for 10 days in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example, I am preparing a report for 1-10 of the month, then 11 to 20 and then 21 to 30. Is there any specific word for 10 days in English like weekly report which consist of 7 days?

Comment: If there were a common word then the idiom "a week or ten days" would likely reflect it.  "A third of the month" is probably the best you can do.

Comment: The auto industry used to report sales using a "10-day period".

Comment: Some works of fantasy and/or science fiction use the term "tenday", but of course you probably shouldn't use that in a business report.

Comment: Check a dictionary for words starting with deca- ; if that doesn't help, check if there is ANY word that means "taking n days" and starts with the latin word for a number, and see if you can make the resulting neologism plausible.

Comment: From the full OED: **decade** definition 2b. [***A period of ten days,** substituted for the week in the French Republican calendar of 1793*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/47971?rskey=SgO6y7&result=1#eid)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't dispute the OED reference, but the common meaning of "decade" is now *ten years*, not ten days.

Comment: @alephzero - did anybody say that "the common meaning" of decade is ten days?

Comment: If you really really want a single word that has this meaning, use tenday or ten-day. It's really obscure, but it does have some usage. However in a business reporting context, you really should use precise terminology, which in this case would be ten-day period, or period of ten days, or similar.

Comment: The generic term is "period", regardless of how you define the period. From a software development perspective, if faced with the same problem, I would adopt a mnemonic of "Period10" or if finance related perhaps "Net10", in terms of reporting I would display this extent as "Period 1/1-1/10, Period 1/11-1/20, Period 1/21-1/30, ..."  if every month has 30 days (such a thing exists in finance) then this is easy. I sometimes use the phrase "Period Ending 1/10", which occasionally confuses people, but it puts focus on the date of the period rather than the length (often more important) HTH!

Comment: Ref: France used [décades or Ten days of the week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Republican_Calendar#Ten_days_of_the_week) as part of the French Republican Calendar.  ... and 3 weeks (décades) to the month.  (Hmm,  similar info in [this comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/363469/is-there-any-word-for-10-days-in-english#comment846594_363469))

Comment: In a very literal sense, this is what [_Decameron_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Decameron#Title) means – but I wouldn’t suggest using that!

Answer (score 13):

No single word is **current usage** for a period of ten days. A week covers a period of seven days, a fortnight covers a period of 14 days, but there is nothing in-between **which can be considered current usage**.

Comment: And in American English, *fortnight* is archaic enough that many speakers don't know how long it is anymore.

Comment: @Joe - you learn something everyday; I was amazed such a useful word could become archaic. In British English it's used all the time, as it's the typical length of a summer holiday. Then I had a look at the USA entry at this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minimum_annual_leave_by_country and I can now understand why it's not needed!

Answer (score 10):

As others suggested, there is no English word that could mean "10 days". But the term "10 day" is broadly used for weather forecast and report. You can use

- 10-day report for the first 10 days of a month
- 10-day report for the middle 10 days of a month
- 10-day report for the last 10 days of a month

Based on context, you can use the first/middle/last part of a month.

Example: [MANDATED 10-DAY REPORT](https://www.mbp.state.md.us/forms/hospdisc.pdf)

[Maryland Board of Physicians]

Answer (score 6):

Something not mentioned before,

> Tri-Monthly

or (more correctly)

> Thrice-Monthly

This would mean there are 3 reports per month, which is accurate, and would make a reasonable fill-in for a single word meaning 10 days.

Comment: February; almost.  :-)

Comment: I am afraid you are confusing *interval* (or *duration*) with *frequency*.

Comment: This isnt really an answer to his question 'exactly', but it does fit his example, and may suit his needs better than the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

***[Decade](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/decade)*** can be used to indicate a group of ten days in a sentence like "[the first decade of the month](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decade%20of%20the%20month%2C%20ten%20days%20of%20the%20month&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdecade%20of%20the%20month%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cten%20days%20of%20the%20month%3B%2Cc0)", but "the first ten days of the month"  is the expression more commonly used:

> - a group, set, or series of ten.

Dictionary.com

Comment: I would say it's ill-advised to use "decade" in this sense, as it would inevitably be read as meaning 10 years.

Comment: -1. When *decade* is used with reference to time, I think the first two definitions in your link (cf *years*) dominate.

Comment: @HotLicks - I am saying that "decade of a month" is a possible but less common option. OP is asking for a single word!!!! Anyway how would "decade of a month" possibly mean a period of ten years.???

Comment: @Lawrence - I am saying that "decade of a month" is a possible but less common option. OP is asking for a single word!!!! Anyway how would "decade of a month" possibly mean a period of ten years.???

Comment: @JOSH I'm saying that the 10-year meaning dominates to the point that "decade of a month" sounds as bad as, say, "hour of a minute".

Comment: @Lawrence -  I agree and I didn't say it does not!!  However bad that may sound it is an expression you can come across, it does exits. I also suggested that "the first ten days of the month" is the expression one would use!

Comment: @Lawrence - "*The harvest began auspiciously **in the last decade of the month*** amid warmer weather, clearing skies and more nearly normal amounts of sunshine*". From: Climatological Data for the United States .https://books.google.it/books?id=ESxEAAAAYAAJ&q=%22decade+of+the+month%22&dq=%22decade+of+the+month%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVw8H87PPQAhUDthQKHU1OA6AQ6AEILTAC

Comment: @JOSH Fair enough, though I'm still not comfortable with applying the 'series of ten' definition you quoted to get 'decade of the month'. It sounds more like an archaic expression or something close to poetic license. I can't retract my -1 as it is now locked, but if you edit your answer to add one or two quotes to demonstrate the 'decade of the month' usage (say, from works referenced by your second link) and ping me, I'll reverse my '-1' vote.

Comment: @Lawrence - no problem for the downvote, I am pleased you reconsidered your view.

Comment: The French decade (the first e has an accent aigu) lasted just a bit more than a decade, but you can still order lobster Thermidor.

Comment: At least the German word "Dekade" means both, 10 days as well as 10 years. I think the same is possible with the English word "decade".

Comment: @rexkogitans Not in British English. Apart from some technical uses in science and engineering (which refer to counting and measuring devices, but *not* specifically to measuring time), "decade" always means "ten years".

Comment: "OP is asking for a single word!!!!" Just because someone asks for something doesn't mean it exists...

Comment: @KyleStrand - incidentally it does exits!!

Comment: Right, but the point is that "this is what OP asked for" isn't really a valid reason to promote confusing/archaic terminology.

Comment: @KyleStrand - why do you feel confused? This is not ELL so we don't give  basic answers. As for usage "decade"  it is not recommended in my answer. Any problem with learning something new? See FF comment above also.

Comment: I didn't say I felt confused, and I'm not objecting because the word you're proposing isn't "basic" enough. I'm objecting because the word pretty obviously does not fit the OP's needs per the question: they say they are "preparing a report", which implies that an archaic usage of a word that currently means something *very different* is not going to be helpful. And yes, I saw FF's comment, which you'll note FF did not think worthy of a full answer.

Comment: @KyleStrand - My answer ***does not recommend*** the use of  the term decade, why do you insist on that point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50107/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-josh).

Comment: Maybe we should incorporate this term in our day to day usage. Then ot will be well known too. I like the term

Comment: @Abcd - the term is actually common usage in other European languages (German, French, Italian and Spanish).

Comment: Unlike *fortnight* which implies a specific unit - the night of which it is forteen, a *decade* is, in principle, 10 of anything. Another example is a set of ten prayers as measured by ten beads on a rosary.

Answer (score 1):

A [decad](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/decad) (note: **not** decade) is:

> A group or set of ten.

Although not specific to days, if you divide a calendar month¹ in a set of three decads, it should be clear from context that it will refer to sets of ten days.  For example:

> *For a higher resolution analysis, we divide each month in three decads, as shown in Figure 12, which shows...*

The meaning in this context should be clear even to readers who are not familiar with the term decad.  And who knows, you might set a trend ;-)

I have seen this usage in a context of climate and weather data analysis.

---

¹In climate models, a year consists of twelve months of exactly 30 days each.  In this case, the division in three decads is exact.

Answer (score 1):

The reason there is no satisfactory term is that we traditionally use a week which is inconsistent with the decade. Most people used non-metric units for most things before the French Revolution. The revolutionaries tried to metricate everything. Some were popular, like the metre, and some weren't, like the 10-day week and the 10-month year.

Answer (score -1):

[dekade](http://zapatopi.net/metrictime/).

> 10 days in a metric week (called a dekade).

Comment: I am sorry, but I am confused. Please correct me if I am wrong. According to the link, "10 days in a metric week" seems to be equal to 7 days in a **non-metric** week that we normally use. How can 10 days in a metric week be 10 days in a **normal** week? How can you use the word in the OP's context?

Comment: @Rathony No, each day is still the same length as in a 7 day week, there's just 3 more. Otherwise you'd be getting up for work at a different time each day.

Comment: According to "metric time", 100 seconds make a minute, 100 minutes make an hour, 10 hours make a day, which means 1,000 minutes (our time) to make one single "metric" hour. Is that correct? Did the OP say he was measuring time according to this system or the ABT (Anglo-Babylonian Time) one?

Comment: @Mari-LouA 10 metric days are exactly the same length as 10 "normal" days. It's still based on the rotation of the earth, anything else would be mad! 1 metric day = 1 normal day, 1 metric hour = 2.4 normal hours.

Comment: No one would ever have any idea what you're talking about using this term.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think that should be "...144 minutes (our time) to make one single 'metric' hour." We seem to have _clearly_ demonstrated one of the concerns raised in that article: using the same _units_ for two different quantities is confusing! It's 100 _metric_-seconds make a _metric_-minute, etc. But a "day" is still the same "day" (length of) regardless of whether it's metric or ABT. Then a "dekade" is a metric-week, which is 10 days. (But why introduce a new unit for a metric-week, but not for metric-seconds, etc.? And where did "dekade" get conjured up from in the first place?)

Comment: @w3d The question asked was, "Is there any word for 10 days in English?" I was only trying to supply an answers. I was not weighing in on the question of a metric week making any sense. :-)  As James P pointed out, a 10 metric hour day can be handled but a 365.25 day year doesn't lend itself to being easily cast into a metric system.  Orbital mechanics can be so messy.

Comment: Is **dekade** pronounced the same way as **decade**?

Comment: Sometimes the metric system really isn't better...

Comment: @kasperd I am thinking yes.  Probably why that spelling was chosen.